# How to get data from OpenWeatherMap API, with Angular 7, using httpClient get method?

Tags: angular

I'm using OpenWeatherMap to get wheater data based on a city name,  and I just want to get data and log them on the console. For start, to see how it works. But it doesn't work and I don't know why?

I saw tutorials but their solutions don't work for me, I don't know why the map is not found, I don't know what to import, or maybe to use something else to send request

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {

  APIkey = 'this is my api key and he is ok';
  URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCurrentWeather(city) {
    return this.http.get(this.URL + city + '&APPID=' + this.APIkey).map((response : Response) => {
      return response.json();   
  })
  }

}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from '../weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  city = 'London';

  constructor(private _weatherService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._weatherService.getCurrentWeather(this.city).subscribe((res) => { console.log(res)});
  }
```

```
compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:18984)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:18877)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:18496)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:19080)
    at compiler.js:19071
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (compiler.js:19070)
    at compiler.js:19043
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I expect in the console to get data about the London and I don't get it instead I get this 3rd picture in the console

Answer (score 0):

The dependency injector in Angular needs to know the **type** of the parameter being injected via the constructor.

```
constructor(private _weatherService: WeatherService) { }
                                     ^^^ must specify the type
```

Comment: My bad, I corrected that and I still have a problem, with a map, like it don't recognize the map, (the map in function get current weather). I want to know how that function needs to look?

Answer (score 0):

function getCurrentWeather needs to look like this, and now it works

```
 getCurrentWeather(city) {
    return this.http.get(this.URL + city + '&APPID=' + this.APIkey);
  }
```